# Converting string to decimal if string isNumeric in SSRS to calculated weighted average

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript

I have a dataset in SSRS with a column that contains both decimals and the string value of 'N/A'.  The SQL casts the column as a string (varchar(10)).
This is an example of the dataset:

```
 Board      Urgency             TicketCounty    AveResTime  AveResolTime
 Support    Open - Priority 2   4               5.766666    N/A
 Support    Priority 1          2               1.833333    0.125925
 IT         Priority 1          3               2.733333    0.875925
 IT         Priority 2          1               0.000000    0.294444
```

In a total row I need to calculate a weighted average for AveResolTime for each Board.
This is the expression that I created:

```
=SUM(Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value * IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value)=1, CDec(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), 0))/SUM(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value)=1, Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value, 0))
```

For the Support Board the value displayed is `#Error` for the IT total the value is `NaN`.

I believe the problem is that the string values in AveResolTime are not being converted when they are all numbers and when the value is 'N/A' is throws an error.
How do I convert the strings to decimals where I can and set the value to 0 when the value is 'N/A'?

I corrected one issue so that if all of the values are numeric, the weighted average is computed.
I removed the `=1'

```
 =SUM(Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value * IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), CDec(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), 0))/SUM(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value, 0))
```

If the value is `N/A`, the 0 value is not used in the calculation and I am still getting the `#Error` in the result.

**UPDATE**
I got the weighted average to calculate using this code:

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), SUM(Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value * CDec(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value, 0)))/SUM(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value, 0)), 0)
```

I had to put the calculation within the if statement.
I still have to take care of the case where all of the values will be 'N/A' and then as @Alan states, there will be an divide by zero error.

Comment: Can you check what datatype the "TicketCounty" column is or just plain wrap it in CInt() to ensure that you are multiplying/dividing by numbers on both sides. Too many times I've had that error and just needed to place a CInt() on an int column.

Comment: The second part of your expression basically says IF Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value is not a number, divide by zero.
It might be easier if you get the expression working for instances where it is numeric and then wrap that in an if that does the numeric test. Can't test at the moment but something like .

IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), YourWorkingExpressionHere, 0). You could replace the final zero with 'Nothing' (no quotes) if you want to show a blank instead of zero.

Comment: To eliminate the 'divide by zero' problem, I changed the expression to only the numerator: `=SUM(Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value * IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), CDec(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value, 0)), 0))`  But I am still getting the `#Error` when one of the values in the Resolution column is **N/A**.

Comment: I added `CInt` around the TicketCount but that value is always an int and greater than 0.  It did not change the results.

Comment: Added the `N/A` when no data is available.  So it looks good.  Thanks all! @AlanSchofield - post your response as the answer and will add my solution to it.

Comment: I would create a **calculated field** to convert the N/A to `CDEC(0)` so you don't have to keep doing the ISNUMERIC everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your expression basically says IF `Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value` is not a number, divide by zero. It might be easier if you get the expression working for instances where it is numeric and then wrap that in an if that does the numeric test. Can't test at the moment but something like .

```
IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), YourWorkingExpressionHere, 0).
```

You could replace the final zero with 'Nothing' (no quotes) if you want to show a blank instead of zero

Comment: This was my final expression:  `=SUM(Fields!TicketCountByPriority.Value * IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value), CDec(IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Valu‌​e), Fields!AverageResolutionTime_BusDays.Value, 0)), 0))`